# Security warning Paypal

Tags: php, web, paypal

When leaving Paypal standard to return to my WP site I get the warning message -

“Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?”
What can be done to prevent this message?

Answer (score 0):

Put your page into `https`. Error is given because a script from an unsecured vendor is requesting data from a secured vendor. It is perfectly harmless in most situations, however an annoying 'feature' in internet explorer.

Comment: I have tried the solution. But https is not working on my site. Is there no other solution apart for me to install SSL cert on my domain????

Comment: Hmm in that case, how can i delay the paypal redirecton. Actaully, it is redirecting after 10sec and the user does not get sufficient time to  click on the continue btn. And hence, the redirected page does not get the paypal submitted data.